# Websites occasionally don't load all the way. What are some possible causes?

Tags: website

Sometimes when I load a webpage, it stops before the entire page has loaded. Maybe the CSS didn't register correctly, or the layout is funky. But when I refresh it loads properly.

What causes this? Does the connection get interrupted? What would cause the interruption and why doesn't the browser recognize this? I'm just curious.

Comment: What browser are you using? This is a common problem with opera 10.

Comment: Have you been adjusting the MTU values in your router recently?

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons I encountered are:

1. Cross-site: Content on the page comes from several sources, some of them are slow or non-existent
2. Some part of the page is generated dynamically by javascript that needs to access Web data or has a bug
3. The item referred to on the page was deleted or renamed
4. Some part of the page was blocked by an extension such as Adblock or NoScript
5. Badly written or badly maintained page

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a DSL connection?  PPPoE, which many DSL providers use to transport your traffic from the DSL modem to the DSL provider's routers, has an MTU of 1492 (because the PPPoE overhead is 8 bytes).  The standard Ethernet MTU is 1500.

I believe if you change the MTU of the network interface connected to your DSL router to 1492 as well the problem should clear up if this is cause.

You may try upgrading the firmware in your DSL modem as well while you are at it.